# How to setup a local repository for packrat?

Tags: r, packrat

I am using packrat_0.4.3 and have some my own packages.

I follow this introduction to create a local repository: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Setting-up-a-package-repository, then use this command to init packrat:

```
packrat::init(options = list(local.repos = c("~/Projects/www/htdocs/R/src/contrib/")))
```

But packrat still cannot find my local packages.

How should I fix it? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The reference cited describes how to set up a CRAN like repository, however for packrat this is not required, you can just create a local directory.

Try this:

```
mkdir ~/local_repo
cp my_package ~/local_repo
```

So that local_repo looks like:

```
local_repo/
  my_package/
    R/
    ...
```

Then in R:

```
packrat::init()
packrat::set_opts(local.repos = c("~/local_repo"))
packrat::install_local('my_package')
```

If some tries this and runs into issues, let me know.  I'm happy to amend the answer until this is resolved.